# Create custom statusbar notification layout with java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I am trying to create a custom statusbar notification layout with java instead of xml. I created a linearlayout, set the required parameters, set it in the notification remoteview, but its giving me FCs. ("Bad notification posted")

Here is my test code:

```
LinearLayout layoutTest;
layoutTest = new LinearLayout(this);
layoutTest.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LayoutParams paramTest = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f); 

layoutTest.setLayoutParams(paramTest);
layoutTest.setId(R.id.mlinearlayout);

contentView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.id.mlinearlayout);
nbuilder.setContent(contentView);
// and all the other notification builder good stuff
```

I am not really familiar with setId(), can that be the problem?
For the id i created /res/values/ids.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item type="id" name="mlinearlayout" />
</resources>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the notification identifier supposed to be an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably related with that `RemoteViews` contructor is expecting the identifier of an XML file, and you're passing the identifier of an element.

Maybe it gives you some more insight looking in the source of RemoteView's methods like `public View apply(Context context, ViewGroup parent)` where the view is inflated, using the layout id.

Do you really have to do it programmatically? XML seems to be the way to go, it's at least the documented one, and I don't see the reson in your code, why you need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! i want to use java instead of xml because the user can change elements in the notification (buttons or imageviews, textview or progressbar etc) and i dont want to have one xml for each setting. Is there a way I can accomplish this with a single xml file?

Comment: Well, without deeper knowledge, or "advanced hacks", I would just group similar views in an xml file and manage small differences/details inside each one, setting the visibilty of the components to "visible" or "gone".

Comment: For bigger differences I would use different XML files.

Comment: at 2016, is there a way to completely create the layout for notification from code?